# Jquery pagination plugin - Next/Previous pagination links to show next/previous full group of page numbers

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, pagination

Jquery pagination plugin - Next/Previous pagination links to show next/previous full group of page numbers

Is there a way to configure the next/previous buttons so that I can achieve the following?

For example,
Pagination like

**First  Prev 1 2 3 4 5 Next  Last**

on clicking "Next" button,

**First  Prev 6 7 8 9 10 Next  Last**

Note: I am using jquery Bootpag plugin
http://botmonster.com/jquery-bootpag/#example-advanced

Comment: Please specify a link to the plugin. What code did you use?

Comment: I have edited my question.Please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the appropriate parameters when initializing the bootpag:

```
...
first: 'First',
last: 'Last',
prev: 'Prev',
next: 'Next',
...
```

```js
$('.pagination').bootpag({
    total: 50,
    page: 2,
    maxVisible: 5,
    leaps: true,
    firstLastUse: true,
    first: 'First',
    last: 'Last',
    prev: 'Prev',
    next: 'Next',
    wrapClass: 'pagination',
    activeClass: 'active',
    disabledClass: 'disabled',
    nextClass: 'next',
    prevClass: 'prev',
    lastClass: 'last',
    firstClass: 'first'
}).on("page", function(event, num){
    $("#content").html("Page " + num); // or some ajax content loading...
});
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//rawgit.com/botmonster/jquery-bootpag/master/lib/jquery.bootpag.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="pagination"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to retain the active page number?

Comment: In my example `num` contains the selected page number.

Comment: Yes.what I am saying  is, for eg assume that we are in 2nd page,when i click "next" button page 6 is being highlighted. I want page 2 be left highlighted until we change the page number

Comment: The bottom of pagination section, the <<>> prev and next should not load the page. It must only scroll and load when a specific page is clicked. - this is my requirement

Comment: This plugin has no such option. You can create an [issue](https://github.com/botmonster/jquery-bootpag/issues).

Comment: Is there any other plugin to do this?Please suggest